# Какой ассемблер выбрать?

Tags: ассемблер

Посоветуйте ассемблер по следующим критериям.

1. Поддерживает ARM архитектуру.
2. Intel синтаксис.
3. Поддерживается в качестве inline в mingw.
4. Наличие литературы.

Спасибо.

Comment: Intel-синтаксис для ARM? Уже смешно :)

Comment: Вы не так поняли.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну поддержка mingw однозначно определяет ответ -- gnu asm. ARM поддерживает, с поправкой на то, что архитектура другая и, соответственно, команды -- тоже другие. Из литературы -- должна быть. Как минимум -- `info as` в юниксоподобных системах

Comment: Погуглил, пишут что только AT&T синтаксис используется, меня это не устраивает.

Comment: Не знаю. Мне странным кажется само желание использовать asm. Но. Есть возможности использовать интеловские синтаксис (`.intel_syntax` директива, -msyntax=INTEL ключ) и мнемоники (`.intel_mnemonic` и `-mmnemonic=INTEL`). В репозитории есть intel2gas -- конвертор из NASM в gas. Разумеется я их не использовал (кроме вставок в .c никакого ассемблера)

Comment: В смысле мнемоники?

Comment: Several x87 instructions, `fadd', `fdiv', `fdivp',
`fdivr', `fdivrp', `fmul', `fsub', `fsubp', `fsubr' and `fsubrp',  are
implemented in AT&T System V/386 assembler with different mnemonics
from those in Intel IA32 specification.

Comment: хорошо а где можно скачать компилятор gas?

Comment: Только называется бинарник as, а не gas. Там, где есть binutils. Т.е. он входит в binutils, вместе с ld и прочими.

Comment: Для его изучения подойдет книга по масм?(если учить именно intel синтаксис)

Comment: не подойдет.

Comment: Тогда дайте линк на какую нибудь документацию, и если сущесвует IDE для gas( в папке с моим mingw голый компилятор)

Comment: Документация... В юникслайках есть texinfo доки. Смотреть `info as`. Но. Это доки только по ассемблеру, но не по архитектуре процессора/ос'ам. Т.е. эти вещи надо смотреть в других местах. IDE... Классика жанра -- [X]Emacs. Возможно есть плагины к Eclipse и т.п. А так -- vim, as, gdb, доки по процессору/системе -- и вперёд.

Comment: Так а где взять отладчик?В вики в описании binutils отладчика не было, подойдет ли gnu debugger?

Comment: gdb должен подойти

Comment: @mikillskegg А куда gdb не смог бы подойти?

Comment: ))))))))))

Comment: @username76 У gdb есть небольшой недостаток -- требует время на изучение/привыкание. Хотя эти затраты ни в коей мере нельзя считать напрасными. Интерфейс -- командный, но есть куча гуёвых фронтендов.
Некоторые лучшим фронтендом считают соответствующий пакет в [X]Emacs.

Comment: Последний вопрос: можно ли с помощью любого из ассемблеров создать объектный файл в котором будет inline функция, этот объектный файл слинковать с проектом и вызвать эту функцию из главного модуля.

Comment: Нет. Если будет объектный файл для функции, то функция -- уже не inline. inline-функции -- это куски кода, которые транслятор вставляет в код на стадии трансляции и для линковщика их уже нет. inline-функциями оформлялись ассемблерные вставки в watcom c/c++